# A condition for the closedness of the image of the closed unitary ball under a bounded operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $L:X \to Y$ be a bounded operator. Let $P$ be the closed unitary ball of $X$. Does it follow that $L(P)$ is closed if $X$ is the dual space of a separable Banach space D? I thought of solving the problem using Banach-Alaouglu theorem, but I can't conclude my reasoning. Since $X$ is the dual of a Banach space D, its unitary ball is weakly$-*$ compact, but the weak$-*$ topology on the unitary ball $P$ is also metrizable because the space $D$ is separable, so we conclude that the unitary ball $P$ is also sequentially weakly$-*$ compact. At this point I thought I was ready to prove that $L(P)$ is closed.
Given $L(x_n)\to y$ with $\{ x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset P$, then ,since $P$ is sequentially weakly$-*$ compact, there exist an $x$ and a subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k}} \}_{k}$ converging to $x$. At this point I was hoping to prove that $L(x_{n_{k}})$ converges weakly$-*$ to $L(x)$ and so to conclude that $y=L(x)$. Since the problem was assigned me without conditions on $Y$ I am not even sure I could speak of weak$-*$ convergence on $Y$, could you think of a condition on $Y$ under which my reasoning could be valid, or could you find another approach to prove the thesis?

Comment: Take $f=(1-1/n)$ in $\ell_\infty$. This is an element of $\ell_1^*$ that does not achieve its norm. If $P$ is the closed unit ball of $\ell_1$, then $f(P)=(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help David!